# Net::Telnet - puts or print string in UTF-8

Tags: ruby, encoding, utf-8, telnet

I'm using an API in which I have to send client informations as a Json-object over a telnet connection (very strange, I know^^).
I'm german so the client information contains very often umlauts or the ß.

**My procedure:**

1. I generate a Hash with all the command information.
2. I convert the Hash to a Json-object.
3. I convert the Json-object to a string (with `.to_s`).
4. I send the string with the Net::Telnet.puts command.

My `puts` command looks like: (cmd is the Json-object)

```
host.puts(cmd.to_s.force_encoding('UTF-8'))
```

In the log files I see, that the Json-object don't contain the umlauts but for example this: `Ã¼` instead of `ü`.

I proved that the string is (with or without the `force_encoding()` command) in UTF-8. So I think that the `puts` command doesn't send the strings in UTF-8.

Is it possible to send the command in UTF-8? How can I do this?

**The whole methods:**

```
host = Net::Telnet::new(
    'Host' => host_string,
    'Port' => port_integer,
    'Output_log' => 'log/'+Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')+'.log',
    'Timeout' => false,
    'Telnetmode' => false,
    'Prompt' => /\z/n
)

def send_cmd_container(host, cmd, params=nil)
    cmd = JSON.generate({'*C'=>'se','Q'=>[get_cmd(cmd, params)]})
    host.puts(cmd.to_s.force_encoding('UTF-8'))
    add_request_to_logfile(cmd)
end

def get_cmd(cmd, params=nil)
    if params == nil
        return {'*C'=>'sq','CMD'=>cmd}
    else
        return {'*C'=>'sq','CMD'=>cmd,'PARAMS'=>params}
    end
end
```

**Addition:**

I also log my sended requests by this method:

```
def add_request_to_logfile(request_string)
    directory = 'log/'
    File.open(File.join(directory, Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')+'.log'), 'a+') do |f|
        f.puts ''
        f.puts '> '+request_string
    end
end
```

In the logfile my requests also don't contain UTF-8 umlauts but for example this: `Ã¼`

Comment: Please show us the code for all four of the steps you describe.

Comment: I have added the methods in which I create the object and send the command. I'm very sorry, but I'm not allowed to post more and more detailed code, but I hope this is enough. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### TL;DR

Set `'Binmode' => true` and use `Encoding::BINARY`.

The above *should* work for you. If you're interested in why, read on.

---

Telnet doesn't really have a concept of "encoding." Telnet just has two modes: Normal mode assumes you're sending 7-bit ASCII characters, and binary mode assumes you're sending 8-bit bytes. You can't tell Telnet "this is UTF-8" because Telnet doesn't know what that means. You can tell it "this is ASCII-7" or "this is a sequence of 8-bit bytes," and that's it.

This might seem like bad news, but it's actually great news, because it just so happens that UTF-8 encodes text as sequences of 8-bit bytes. `früh`, for example, is five bytes: `66 72 c3 bc 68`. This is easy to confirm in Ruby:

```
puts str = "\x66\x72\xC3\xBC\x68"
# => früh
puts str.bytes.size
# => 5
```

In Net::Telnet we can turn on binary mode by passing the `'Binmode' => true` option to `Net::Telnet::new`. But there's one more thing we have to do: Tell Ruby to treat the string like binary data, i.e. a sequence of 8-bit bytes.

You already tried to use `String#force_encoding`, but what you might not have realized is that `String#force_encoding` doesn't actually convert a string from one encoding to another. Its purpose isn't to change the data's encoding—its purpose is to tell Ruby what encoding the data is *already* in:

```
str = "früh"   # => "früh"
p str.encoding # => #<Encoding:UTF-8>
p str[2]       # => "ü"

p str.bytes    # => [ 102, 114, 195, 188, 104 ] # This is the decimal represent-
                                                # ation of the hexadecimal bytes
                                                # we saw before, `66 72 c3 bc 68`

str.force_encoding(Encoding::BINARY) # => "fr\xC3\xBCh"
p str[2]       # => "\xC3"

p str.bytes    # => [ 102, 114, 195, 188, 104 ] # Same bytes!
```

Now I'll let you in on a little secret: `Encoding::BINARY` is just an alias for `Encoding::ASCII_8BIT`. Since ASCII-8BIT doesn't have multi-byte characters, Ruby shows `ü` as two separate bytes, `\xC3\xBC`. Those bytes aren't printable characters in ASCII-8BIT, so Ruby shows the `\x##` escape codes instead, but the data hasn't changed—only the way Ruby prints it has changed.

So here's the thing: Even though Ruby is now *calling* the string BINARY or ASCII-8BIT instead of UTF-8, it's still the same bytes, which means *it's still UTF-8*. Changing the encoding it's "tagged" as, however, means when Net::Telnet does (the equivalent of) `data[n]` it will always get one byte (instead of potentially getting multi-byte characters as in UTF-8), which is just what we want.

### And so...

```
host = Net::Telnet::new(
         # ...all of your other options...
         'Binmode' => true
       )

def send_cmd_container(host, cmd, params=nil)
  cmd = JSON.generate('*C' => 'se','Q' => [ get_cmd(cmd, params) ])
  cmd.force_encoding(Encoding::BINARY)
  host.puts(cmd)
  # ...
end
```

(Note: `JSON.generate` always returns a UTF-8 string, so you never have to do e.g. `cmd.to_s`.)

### Useful diagnostics

A quick way to check what data Net::Telnet is actually sending (and receiving) is to set the `'Dump_log'` option (in the same way you set the `'Output_log'` option). It will write both sent and received data to a log file in hexdump format, which will allow you to see if the bytes being sent are correct. For example, I started a test server (`nc -l 5555`) and sent the string `früh` (`host.puts "früh".force_encoding(Encoding::BINARY)`), and this is what was logged:

> ```
> > 0x00000: 66 72 c3 bc  68 0a                                  fr..h.
> ```

You can see that it sent six bytes: the first two are `f` and `r`, the next two make up `ü`, and the last two are `h` and a newline. On the right, bytes that aren't printable characters are shown as `.`, ergo `fr..h.`. (By the same token, I sent the string `I❤NY` and saw `I...NY.` in the right column, because `❤` is three bytes in UTF-8: `e2 9d a4`).

So, if you set `'Dump_log'` and send a `ü`, you should see `c3 bc` in the output. If you do, congratulations—you're sending UTF-8!

**P.S.** Read Yehuda Katz' article [Ruby 1.9 Encodings: A Primer and the Solution for Rails](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/05/05/ruby-1-9-encodings-a-primer-and-the-solution-for-rails/). In fact, read it yearly. It's really, really useful.

Comment: Really helpful and detailed answer. Thanks for that!